# Splitting a dataframe of unique_id indexed sparse features into a percentage test/train

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains sparse features encoded as follows

```
user,item,rating
a,x,1
a,y,2
b,x,3
b,z,4
b,w,5
b,y,1
c,x,1
c,y,1
```

I want to create a test and train set of disjoint users data based on a percentage. So for example if I set P=66% I'd get the following (2/3 of the users are in the first group, 1/3 in the second group)

```
user,item,rating
a,x,1
a,y,2
b,x,3
b,z,4
b,w,5
b,y,1
------
c,x,1
c,y,1
```

The dataframe contains millions of rows... I tried the following and it is horrifically slow. Any ideas on how I should approach this -- it seems really simple:

```
import math

unique_users = df.groupby('user')['user'].unique()

TRAIN_PERCENTAGE = 0.66

total = unique_devices.shape[0]
train = math.floor(TRAIN_PERCENTAGE * total)

train_device_ids = unique_users.iloc[:train]
test_device_ids = unique_user.iloc[train+1:]

train_set = df[df['user'].isin(train_device_ids)]
test_set = df[df['user'].isin(test_device_ids)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the dataframe by `user` and then use [`.searchsorted`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) to find index where to split:

```py
TRAIN_PERCENTAGE = 0.66

df = df.sort_values(by="user", ignore_index=True)
unique_users = df.user.unique()

first_group = unique_users[: int(TRAIN_PERCENTAGE * len(unique_users)) + 1]
idx = df.user.searchsorted(first_group[-1], side="right")

train_set = df[:idx]
test_set = df[idx:]

print(train_set)
print()
print(test_set)
```

Prints:

```
  user item  rating
0    a    x       1
1    a    y       2
2    b    x       3
3    b    z       4
4    b    w       5
5    b    y       1

  user item  rating
6    c    x       1
7    c    y       1
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind using the `scikit-learn` library, they have a really helpful function called `train_test_split` that might be faster.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_set, test_set = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.33)
```

There are other parameters like `shuffle` and `stratify` that you can pass to customize your split. You can read more about in the docs [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).

Comment: this doesn't answer the user split directly